# ZFS: usedbydataset value unusually large on one zpool

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux

I have a 500T ZFS server with 8 `zpools`. The usage overall is pretty moderate. However, I noticed that on one of the zpools the `usedbydataset` value is as large as `24.2T`. The actual user data on this zpool is just about `4T`. The other `zpools` have pretty moderate values. See below:

```
$ zfs list|egrep '(^jbodp4 |^NAME)'
NAME                   USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
jbodp4                28.0T  20.0T  24.2T  /zfs/4

$ zfs list|egrep '^jbodp4\/'
jbodp4/user1        219K  5.00T   219K  /zfs/4/user1
jbodp4/user2          144G  4.86T   144G  /zfs/4/user2
jbodp4/user3         4.87G  5.00T  4.87G  /zfs/4/user3
jbodp4/user4       3.69T  1.31T  3.69T  /zfs/4/user4

$ zfs get all|egrep '(^jbodp[0-9] |^intp[0-9] )' | grep 'usedbydataset'
intp1                 usedbydataset         219K                   -
intp2                 usedbydataset         252G                   -
intp3                 usedbydataset         219K                   -
jbodp4                usedbydataset         24.2T                  -
jbodp5                usedbydataset         16.1G                  -
jbodp6                usedbydataset         1.42T                  -
jbodp7                usedbydataset         901G                   -
jbodp8                usedbydataset         329K                   -
```

Could someone help me identify why this particular jbod has such a high usage for `usedbydataset` and how could I find more about this dataset.

Comment: Look for snapshots.... `zfs list -t snapshot`

Comment: @ewwhite I do not see anything indicative in the output of the command you mentioned: `NAME               USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
intp1/home1@base  9.62G      -  5.29T  -
`

Comment: Does it contain any non-sparse zvols with large reservations (or any other reservations for that matter)?

Comment: Look for other files/folders in "/zfs/4" - it's possible to create files in a zpool without first creating a dataset.